# Misunderstanding the integration of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision, numerical-integration

everybody!

Could you, guys, please explain why the answer for the exact integration

```
quad( @(x)x.^3-2.*x,0,2)
```

is

```
-2.220446049250313e-016
```

istead of a zero, just like it should be?

Comment: floating point precision all over again. Numerical Recipes, or any other book on number crunching will tell you how floating point errors propagate and how to avoid the pathetic cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `quad` function computes the integral numerically, not symbolically.

Even though most integration methods will compute the integral of a 3rd degree polynomial 'exactly' , that is only true if all the calculations are done exactly as well. When doing the calculation on a computer, round-off error still is a factor.